# How could extend two section inside one Laravel View form?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

i am facing one problem that the fullcalendar didnt work with the laravel. I have checked the maddhatter one, but i think if i start from zero will make me more clear about it.

I create one folder named layouts, and it contains two file name `app.blade.php` and `cal.blade.php` . And i have another file name `home.blade.php` which is my homepage.
The code in the page is like this.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@endsection
```

First i extends this, then the out come is like this.
[Laravel 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0l0r.png)

Then the second one, i put this code:

```
@extends('layouts.cal')

@section('content1')

    <div id="calendar"></div>

@endsection
```

And it works fine, the result is like this.
[Laravel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPjsO.png). But when i put this two code together, it doesnot works will.

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')

    @endsection
    @extends('layouts.cal')

    @section('content1')

    <div id="calendar"></div>

    @endsection
```

The same result as the laravel 1.
I not sure what is going wrong at my code, when put two together only one works. But separate it works fine.
Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

> app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#spark-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Laravel
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="spark-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->email }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>



                    @endif

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @yield('content')

    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

> cal.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}
    <script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#eventdata").show();
                    $("#eventdata").load("/events/add/"+allDay+"/"+$.fullCalendar.formatRange( date, 'dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm'));
                },

            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


@yield('content1')
</body>
</html>
```

---

**After apply the method that @Ravi mention, this is my works.**

```
app.blade.php

@extends('layouts.cal')
        @section('content')




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#spark-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Laravel
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="spark-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->email }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>



                    @endif

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>



    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@endsection
@section('content1')
    <div id="calendar"></div>
    @endsection

</body>
</html>
```

---

cal.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}
    <script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#eventdata").show();
                    $("#eventdata").load("/events/add/"+allDay+"/"+$.fullCalendar.formatRange( date, 'dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm'));
                },

            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')

@yield('content1')
</body>
</html>
```

Home.blade.php

```
    @include ('layouts.app')
```

It still show the Laravel 1.

Comment: post your `app.blade.php` and `cal.blade.php` content

Comment: @sstarlight I have updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is just an example. You can test it and do your modifications.

> cal.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>



</head>
<body id="app-layout">
@yield('content')

@yield('content1')

    <script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
     <!-- JavaScripts -->
    {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#eventdata").show();
                    $("#eventdata").load("/events/add/"+allDay+"/"+$.fullCalendar.formatRange( date, 'dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm'));
                },

            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> app.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.cal')

@section('content')

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#spark-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Laravel
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="spark-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->email }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>



                    @endif

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

@endsection

@section('content1')
    <div id="calendar"></div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Nope, after i try the two answer that you provide, then it works now. I didnt change the cal.blade.php ,just change the app.blade.php like this.  `@extends('layouts.cal') @section('content') @end @section('content1') <div id="calendar"></div> @end ` It works. Thanks.

Comment: but when i logout, it will show up the calendar also. Should use the if for the section?

Comment: nvm, i fixed that by put them into the if else statement.

Comment: Brother Auth::check and Auth::guest both are very useful functions.  It will help you to display specific content to Authentic user and hide them to guest user.

Comment: Excellent answer! (y)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

=>   In `cal.blade.php`

```
@yield('content')


@yield('content1')
```

=> In `app.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.cal')

@section('content')
  // do your stuff here    
@end

@section('content1')        
     <div id="calendar"></div>    
@end
```

=> in `home.blade.php`

```
@include('layouts.app')
```

Comment: Hi, i try your method. But still didnt works fine. But thanks. @RaviHirani

Comment: Brother you are loading HTML two times please set your all css and js in cal.blade.php. then after extend it in app.blade.php.

Comment: but that cal.blade.php css and js is for the calendar view. You mean change all the css in one blade.php

Comment: Yes you are getting my point in right direction.  It is very best practice to keep all our essential css and js files at one  blade file.  then extend it to another blade and using yield function you can set manual js for particular page also.

Comment: Ya, but i have another problem maybe you can help me see it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594226/layout-will-crash-after-loading-finish-with-laravel    @RaviHirani