# The align of the laravel not properly cause by multiple embedded css and external css in one blade file

Tags: php, laravel, layout, laravel-blade

I am using laravel as my framework, i am facing the problem which is i @extends a php into another php, it works fine. But i not sure why the layout will become strange when the page is loading finish.

This is my code

```
@extends('layouts.cal')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#spark-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Branding Image -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                Laravel
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="spark-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    @section('content1')
                        <div id="calendar"></div>
                        @endsection
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

@yield('content')

        <!-- JavaScripts -->
{{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My cal.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}
    <script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#eventdata").show();
                    $("#eventdata").load("/events/add/"+allDay+"/"+$.fullCalendar.formatRange( date, 'dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm'));
                },

            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


@yield('content1')


</body>
</html>
```

What i added is

```
@extends('layouts.cal')
```

And in the if else statement, i add

```
@section('content1')
 <div id="calendar"></div>
@endsection
```

The function works fine, i just cant find out what is the problem why the layout will change when the page is loading finish.
[image: Laravel Page]

---

**I tried this method.**

```
@extends('layouts.cal')
@section('content')
//my code here
@if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    @section('content1')
                        <div id="calendar"></div>
                        @endsection
                @endif


@endsection
```

It is still works, but the problem is the navigation bar of the page will be disappear when the user is not login.

---

After modified the cal.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}

    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                $("#eventdata").show();
                $("#eventdata").load("/events/add/"+allDay+"/"+$.fullCalendar.formatRange( date, 'dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm'));
            },

        });

    });

</script>

@yield('main_add_js')


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always start your HTML with your first blade template.  Your first blade template is `cal.blade.php`. So start your HTML and body tag on that file.

Your all essential CSS files should be included in this file.

For eg:-

Your `cal.blade.php` file should be

```
<html>
<head>
    // Add all your essential CSS files here.
 @yield('manual_add_css_section')
    // This yield section isoptional for you
</head>

<body>

 @yield('main_content_section')
  // This is the main content section. 2nd blade file will use this section. In your case you are using for displaying calender.    

   // Include all your required Js Files here just above `</body>` tag.

 @yield('manual_add_js_section')
   // This yield section is optional for you to use script tag. It will load at the end.
</body>
</html>
```

> cal.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    {{--<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />--}}

    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;@section('content')
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>



@yield('content')

@if (Auth::user())
<div id="calendar"></div>
@endif

<script src='js/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Check calender div is exist or not. 
      // In case of guest user it will not present
      if($("#calendar").length ){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                $("#eventdata").show();
                $("#eventdata").load("/events/add/"+allDay+"/"+$.fullCalendar.formatRange( date, 'dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm'));
            },

        });
       }

    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I have not make too much changes here. I have added this lines to body section.

```
@if (Auth::user())
<div id="calendar"></div>
@endif
```

> app.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.cal')
@section('content')

                @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                @endif


@endsection
```

I have removed @section('content1') from this file because there is no need to use it here. I have taken that section into `carl.blade.php` file. Perhaps you can use it anywhere you want.

Hope this will work for you .

All the best. :)

Comment: i have added my cal.blade.php

Comment: First put your all manual script tags to just above </body> tag in cal.blade.php.

Comment: Do not start second head tag, Meta tag, Title tag, Style tag in your app.blade.php

Comment: app.blade.php file just only extents content section of cal.blade.php. So transfer your all css and js files to cal.blade.php. As I explained you can make optional yield sections to your cal.blade.php file for adding dynamic css and js if it is required.

Comment: I not sure what you means by the second head tag, meta tag, title tag, style tag in the app.blade.php.  I have modified the cal.blade.php ,is that what you means?

Comment: Use the section that can transfer the css and the js into it already?

Comment: I am looking your files. cal.blade.php seems good looking now. but I am afraid that you have missed yield('content') section just after <body> tag.

Comment: I just want to try, i dont understand why the @section('content') can straight use in the cal.blade.php without @extends the app.blade.php and endsection

Comment: I got change the 
`@yield('content1')

@if (Auth::user())
    <div id="calendar"></div>
@endif`
Then the code works, it wont loading so long and come out two login. But still the layout will change like the picture i show above.

Comment: It works, when i put the `<style>

    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>` into the app.blade.php . Then everythings look ok now, bro. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are override the bootstrap css ad, pass the css you need for the fullcalendar into the master layout file. This will works, hope this can help.

```
  <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
```

So this will no produce the conflict.